# How to Use JSON Object to populate Knockout Form

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, jspdf

I have a form that i would like to populate using knockout data-binding from a JSON object. I have hard coded the values using knockout. What i am really after is since i have a JSON object how do i turn that into data that knockout can use to populate my form dynamically? Here is my [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/2bwegmsv/)

```
 <p>Hero Name: <span data-bind="text : HeroName" /></p>
 <p>Agent Writing Number: <span data-bind="text : HeroCode" /></p>
 <p>Contact Phone:  <span data-bind="text : ContactPhone" /></p>


var HeroDetails = $.get("GetHeroDetailsForVillianView", {
                HeroRequestIdForvillianDetailsView: HeroRequestIdForVillianDetailsView
            }, function (returnDataForDetails) {
                var results = JSON.parse(returnDataForDetails);

   $('#json').text(JSON.stringify({HeroName:'PeterParker', ContactPhone: '123456', HeroCode: 3 }, null, 4));


 function ViewModel() {
var self = this;

 self.HeroName = ko.observable("Peter Parker");
        self.ContactPhone = ko.observable("123456858");
        self.HeroCode = ko.observable("2455654");

 }

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Inside the `ViewModel` you need to set the new values. The variables are already observable so you need to `self.HeroName(results.HeroName)`. That implies you move the success callback of that `$.get` inside `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) page of the KO documentation for more details. You might also be interested in the [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin.

Here is the pattern I use:

```
function ViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.HeroName = ko.observable(data.HeroName);
  self.ContactPhone = ko.observable(data.PhoneNumber);
  self.HeroCode = ko.observable(data.HeroCode);

}

var viewModel;
$.getJSON("/some/url", function(data) { 
    viewModel = new ViewModel(data);
})

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: What if the JSON object is outside of my viewmodel? How would i got about reaching it from the viewmodel?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. You have to give the viewModel a reference to your objects. You might want to open a new question with a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but pretty simple with jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/2bwegmsv/4/

I added ids to each of the divs where you want the data and then added this to your javascript:

```
var myJson = {HeroName:'PeterParker', ContactPhone: '123456', HeroCode: 3 };

    $('#hname').append(myJson.HeroName);
    $('#agent').append(myJson.ContactPhone);
    $('#contact').append(myJson.HeroCode);
```

May not work precisely as you want, but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I was originally going to use Jquery and be done with it. Knockout is used extensively in the solution and is requisite unfortunately. Thanks for the excellent response.

Comment: It looks like @Ryan's answer should give you what you need then.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically: Just binding JSON object.

```
var jsonDataViewModel = {HeroName:'Peter Parker', ContactPhone: '123456', HeroCode: 3}; 
ko.applyBindings(jsonDataViewModel);
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html